# Cannot Edit item in CRUD using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I make CRUD in Laravel 8 , I Cannot make Edit category in CRUD even I added the route name with the category ID in index.blade.php file, I got this error, I checked the file many times before posting here, still I did not catch the error ... please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egiJN.png)

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Edit Category</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <ul>
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                </ul>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endif 
                    <form action="{{ route('category.update', ['id' => $category->id]) }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        {{-- @method('PUT') --}}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Category Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $category->name }}">
                        </div>                      
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </form>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

CategoryController

```
    public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        return view('category.edit')->with(['category' => $category]);
    }

   public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $request->validate([

            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',

        ]);

        // $category->name = $request['name'];

        // $category->update();

        $category->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('category_updated', 'Category has been updated');
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    
    Route::get('/categories', [CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('category.index');

    Route::get('/category/create', [CategoryController::class, 'create'])->name('category.create');

    Route::post('/category', [CategoryController::class, 'store'])->name('category.store');

    Route::get('/category/{id}/edit', [CategoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('category.edit');

    Route::post('/category/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'update'])->name('category.update');

    Route::delete('/category/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('category.delete');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you change

```
   public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
```

to

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

and tell me the result?

try this if it works, we will improve it:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([

            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',

        ]);

        $category = Category::find($id);

        // $category->name = $request['name'];

        // $category->update();

        $category->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('category_updated', 'Category has been updated');
    }
```

Comment: It gives an error (Undefined variable '$category')

Comment: at least you don't have your previous error, so you went to the next step.